# Using apply() on a promise and not able to access promise response data

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, axios

I'm calling the apply method on a function that returns a promise and I'm having issues getting the response data after the apply method was called.

```
getData(data) {
    axios.post('/post/something', data)
         .then(res => console.log(res)); // Returns 'Success'
}

callService(args, fn) {
    return fn.apply(this, args)
             .then(() => this.doSomethingElse())
             .then(res => console.log(res)); // Returns undefined
}


callService([1,2], getData);
```

Why does fn.apply contain a promise but not the data that was sent back from the server?  What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: `res` would be the value that `this.doSomethingElse()` returns.

Comment: Also you cannot "use" apply on a promise. You are using apply to call a function that returns a promise.

Comment: Yea, I wasn't sure what was going on and had a bit of trouble trying to explain what I was trying to achieve. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does fn.apply contain a promise but not the data that was sent back from the server?

`callService` returns a promise that resolves to the return value of `this.doSomethingElse()`, which apparently is `undefined`. This is what happens when you chain `.then` calls. The promise returned by `.then` resolves to the return value of the function passed to it. [You can learn more about promises on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).

> What is the correct way to do this?

I guess you want this:

```
callService(args, fn) {
    return fn.apply(this, args)
             .then(res => {
                this.doSomethingElse();
                return res;
             });
}
```

Or if `doSomethingElse` returns a promise:

```
callService(args, fn) {
    return fn.apply(this, args)
             .then(res => this.doSomethingElse().then(() => res));
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks Felix. I didn't realise when chaining .then() they took in the response of the previous one. Was a fundamental misunderstanding on my behalf.  I'll accept this answer.

Comment: If it's any consolation, I made the same mistake when I first learned about promises :)